# Handle "start page" in Windows Printer Driver

Tags: events, printing, driver

I created v3 printer driver for specific printer. It implements IPrintOemUni interface. My current task is to handle some kind of "Start Page" event to determine if it is enough paper for the current page. Please suggest how it is possible to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Check interface IPrintOemUni - probably it has something for that

Answer (score 1):

It can be done via DDI OEM Hook functions
DRVFN[] should be created and then used in EnableDriver()

```
HRESULT __stdcall TestDriver::EnableDriver(
        DWORD          dwDriverVersion,
        DWORD          cbSize,
        PDRVENABLEDATA pded)
{
    pded->iDriverVersion =  PRINTER_OEMINTF_VERSION;
    pded->c = sizeof(s_aOemHookFuncs) / sizeof(DRVFN);
    pded->pdrvfn = (DRVFN *) s_aOemHookFuncs;
    return S_OK;
}
```